# Issues saving a OneToMany relationship in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

We are using Ember-Data with the standard RestAdapter and so far so good. We are able to save objects with OneToOne and ManyToMany relationships, but when we try to save an object with a OneToMany relationship, any objects added to the many side are discarded when `save()` is called. Code below:

The 2 models:

```
Ember.Owner = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  pets: DS.hasMany('pet', {async: true});
});

Ember.Pet = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  owner: DS.belongsTo('owner', {async: true});
});
```

The controller code:

```
actions: {

        save:  function() {

            var self = this;

            var petSaved = function(pet) {

                 // Create the owner
                 var owner = self.store.createRecord ('owner', {
                        name: 'Walt',
                 });

                // Add the new pet then save the owner
                owner.get('pets').then(function(pets) {
                    pets.addObject(pet);
                    // Logging the owner at this point shows that pet has been added and has been assigned an id from the DB
                    owner.save();
                    // Logging the owner at this point shows no pets
                });
            };

            // Create the pet
            var pet = this.store.createRecord('pet', {
                name: 'Lassie',
            });

            // Save the pet
            pet.save().then(petSaved);
        },
    },
```

Using code substantially similar to the above, we can successfully save ManyToMany and OneToOne relationships, but for some reason this code fails. After much Googling, we have read that this is either an EmberData bug or an explicit design decision by Ember due to efficiency considerations, but the latter does not make sense as ManyToMany relationships can be saved this way.

We would be very grateful for any insights into this issue and how it can be fixed please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the `DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin` into your `App.OwnerSerializer`.

It should look something like...

```
App.OwnerSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
  attrs: {
    pets: {serialize: 'ids', deserialize: 'ids'}
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but can you explain why this is necessary please?

Comment: The short answer is that there are many combinations of serialize and deserialize that can happen based on the api being used. So Ember Data makes you choose which way you'd like it to work. But I do agree that the default should be `serialize: 'ids'`.